# Coloring graphics with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have been using the `fadings` tikz library for colouring images (`png` and `pdf`, mostly) in LaTeX with the code below. The only two libraries I am using here are `tikz` and `graphicx`.

```
% Importing the image
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=theimage,inner sep=0]
    \node [fill={transparent!0}]
    {\includegraphics{nameoftheimage}}; 
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

% Printing "theimage"
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0]
% Colouring
\path[scope fading=theimage,fit fading=false];
\node[fill=magenta, minimum width=thewidth, minimum height=theheight]{}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When I do this, I obtain the following image:

[image: Processed image]

That is already great. The problem is that the source file has to be:

[image: Source image]

instead of:

[image: Original image]

This forces me to invert the colouring of all the images I want to use. I've googled the `tikzfadingfrompicture` function, but I found nothing useful. (Nor in the `tikz` documentation.) Is there an easy way to manipulate the code above so that it is not necessary to invert the colours of the original picture? Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you note yourself, your method "inverts the picture", i.e. does the step you do by hand. You could just store this result in a `\savebox`, the inverted version of gives the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newsavebox{\cheat}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=theimage,inner sep=0]
    \node[fill=transparent!0]
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}}; 
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\savebox\cheat{\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0]
\node(img){\phantom{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}}};
\fill[path fading=theimage,fit fading=false] (img.south west) rectangle (img.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=inverted,inner sep=0]
    \node[fill=transparent!0]
    {\usebox\cheat}; 
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\tikz[baseline={(pic.base)}]{\node(pic){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}};}
& \tikz[baseline={(pic.base)}]{\node(pic){\usebox\cheat};} &
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0]
\node(img){\phantom{\usebox\cheat}};
\fill[magenta,path fading=inverted,fit fading=false] (img.south west) rectangle (img.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
original & inverted & inverted twice
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And you can make this a macro so that you do not have to redo these steps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newsavebox{\cheat}
\newcommand{\FadeShade}[2][]{\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=theimage,inner sep=0]
    \node[fill=transparent!0]
    {#2}; 
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
\savebox\cheat{\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0]
\node(img){\phantom{#2}};
\fill[path fading=theimage,fit fading=false] (img.south west) rectangle (img.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=inverted,inner sep=0]
    \node[fill=transparent!0]
    {\usebox\cheat}; 
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0]
\node(img){\phantom{\usebox\cheat}};
\fill[#1,path fading=inverted,fit fading=false] (img.south west) rectangle (img.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\FadeShade[magenta]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}}
~
\FadeShade[blue]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-duck}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am studying your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer pointed me into the right direction. I was intending to use this method for creating a macro. When I finish it I am going to share it. (I will also give you the proper credits.) Thanks.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I have just given a flag for your comment. What are you doing in this friendly forum?

Comment: @Black Mild: I do not understand what you want or what you are talking about. I deleted my comment